# Как создать новый лист в существующем excel файле c#

Tags: c#, excel

Хочу добавить в существующий excel-файл новый лист и туда вставить данные. Вот код:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string processed_data = @"D:\BoilingConsole\outfile.xlsx";
Excel.Application excel_out = new();
excel_out.Visible = false;
excel_out.UserControl = false;
Excel.Workbook wb_out;

wb_out = excel.Workbooks.Open(processed_data);
Excel.Worksheet ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets.Add("Обработка");

ws_out.Cells[1, 1] = "Time";
ws_out.Cells[1, 2] = "q";
ws_out.Cells[1, 3] = "dT";
ws_out.Cells[1, 4] = "U";

wb_out.Save();
wb_out.Close();
excel_out.Application.Quit();
```

В строке, где добавляю новый лист выдает ошибку: Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): 0x800A03EC
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.Add(Object Before, Object After, Object Count, Object Type)
at Program.$(String[] args) in D:\Programming\C#\BoilingConsole\BoilingConsole\Program.cs:line 136.
Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: У метода `Worksheets.Add` нет аргумента "название". Создайте лист без названия, потом переименуйте.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.